# Disallow hg push -f - but allow hg pull creating new head

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

As a followup for [Mercurial: enforce "hg pull -u" before "hg commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175538/mercurial-enforce-hg-pull-u-before-hg-commit)
I have started to use a hook

```
[hooks]
pretxnchangegroup.forbid_2heads = /usr/local/bin/forbid_2head.sh
```

where forbid_2head.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
BRANCH=`hg branch`
COUNT=`hg heads --template '{branch}|{rev}\n' | grep ^${BRANCH} | wc -l` 
if [ "$COUNT" -ne "1" ] ; then 
   echo "=========================================================="
   echo "Trying to push more than one head, which is not allowed"
   echo "You seem to try to add changes to an old changeset!"
   echo "==========================================================" 
   exit 1 
fi 
exit 0
```

It is derivative of the script found at http://tutorials.davidherron.com/2008/10/forbidding-multiple-heads-in-shared.html
where I do allow multiple named branches.

The problem I have now is that

- it stops hg push -f which is what I wanted
- it also stops hg pull in case there are incoming changeset and I have commits outgoing. This is indeed bad

Can I in any way reuse the same script but change the hook setup and stop "hg push -f"?
Or can I in forbid_2head.sh know whether this is a push or pull command running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the script isn't completely correct: it just counts the number of heads in the branch currently checked out on the server (the one `hg branch`) reports. You could improve it by using

```sh
hg heads tip
```

to get the heads of the branch of `tip`. But someone might push changesets on more than one branch at a time, so what you really want is

```sh
hg heads --template '{branch}\n' $HG_NODE:tip
```

to find branch heads for the branches touched by `$HG_NODE:tip` (the changesets pushed in the not-yet-committed transaction). You can then compare that with

```sh
hg log --template '{branch}\n' -r $HG_NODE:tip | sort -u
```

which are the branches touched by the changegroup.

If you don't want to allow existing multiple heads, then you can simplify the above to just

```sh
$(hg heads --template 'x' | wc -c) -eq $(hg branches | wc -l)
```

which just tests that the number of branch heads is equal to the number of branches — i.e., that there is exactly one branch head per named branch.

With that out of the way, let me mention `$HG_SOURCE`. That environment variable is set by Mercurial when it runs the hook: it has the value `push` if the changegroup is being pushed into the repository using direct filesystem access, and the value `serve` if the changegroup is coming in over SSH or HTTP. See [the Mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec%3ahook%3asources).

So, to conclude, I believe this is a good "forbid multiple heads" script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
HEADS=$(hg heads --template 'x' | wc -c)
BRANCHES=$(hg branches | wc -l)
test $HG_SOURCE = 'serve' -a $HEADS -ne $BRANCHES
```